# Adding / removing points from the list - live plot

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

My purpose is to animate a (list) plot by removing points from it (adding ones to it) live. I would like to show how these actions influence my plot and my error (it should also change live as I remove some points).
Is it possible in *Mathematica*? I already know how to show the list flow, but it's not quite what I was looking for.
I would be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: How do you want to add/remove points? Explicitly typing out coordinates? Clicking on the plot itself?

Comment: Clicking on the points / plot itself was what I was thinking about. Typing out coordinates would do as well, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a proof of concept (which you can adjust to your needs), here is a `Manipulate[]` that demonstrates least-squares fitting of a line to a set of points:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], ColorData[97, 3]], lsline[pts]},
                     {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[7], ColorData[97, 2]], Point[pts]}},
                    Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 5/2],
           {{pts, RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {2, 2}]}, Locator, 
            Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}, 
           Initialization :> (lsline[pts_] := InfiniteLine[{0, #1}, {1, #2}] & @@ 
                              LeastSquares[Transpose[PadLeft[{pts[[All, 1]]},
                                                             {2, Automatic}, 1]],
                                           pts[[All, 2]]]), SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Manipulate]

The most relevant part here is the use of a `Locator` control within `Manipulate[]` with the set option `LocatorAutoCreate -> True`; with this, in addition to being able to drag points around the plot, you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click on points to remove them, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click on a blank area to add points.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!